# How to pass time_t by reference into a function

Tags: c++11

I have a function definition like this:

```
double getPriceTimeByPtr(const StrategyParams* ptr, const int applied_price, const int timeframe, const int shift, const int shift_delta, const bool normalized, time_t &time);
```

but when I compile this code it errors just before the &time part so clearly there is a problem passing a time_t object by reference.

How do I fix this please?

I recently added the time_t parameter to the function and the error occurred since then.

Here's the errors generated:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression 
State
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ')' before '&'        
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing '{' before '&'        
Error   C2059   syntax error: '&'   
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'
```

The syntax seems correct to me but the compiler doesn't like it.

Comment: To me that looks like the compiler doesn't know what `time_t` is. Have you tried including the correct header? `<ctime>`

Comment: BTW, adding `const` for that `bool` and `int` makes no difference.

Comment: Are you sure that you are compiling with C++ compiler and not with C compiler?

Comment: @SombreroChicken thanks for your comments. Yes, #include <ctime> is included in my header file. Noted about the const.

Comment: @gudok I'm using visual studio and the premake5 file for the sub project is defined with language c++ so yes, I believe it is. It was working before I added the time_t element so I don't think it is that.

Comment: @gudok Actually, thinking about it again, I think you have kind of hit the nail on the head. The project that is failing to compile is a C project so I can't pass by reference from the C project. Will need to use pointers I think. I'll give it a go and see.

Answer (score 0):

The project that was failing was defined as a C project which was then trying to call a C++ function by reference. C can't us by reference so was failing. Changing the time parameters to pointers worked.